# what is the right way for not supporting resolution below 320x480

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, apk

I am creating layouts for my app, and as I understand the above screen resolution is the threshold resolution and devices below it are extremely rare or too cheap, how can I detect a device which does not comply with this resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this element in the Manifest file 
`<screen android:screenSize=["small" | "normal" | "large" | "xlarge"]`

```
<compatible-screens>
 <screen android:screenSize="small"/>
 <screen android:screenSize="normal"/>
 <screen android:screenSize="large"/>
 <screen android:screenSize="xlarge"/>
</compatible-screens>
```

small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp